# how to save a http get method return png file

Tags: javascript, c++, http, get

I have a quesiton, 
there is a http get method URL, like this:

http://tile0.tianditu.com/DataServer?T=A0512_EMap&X=1&Y=0&L=2
also I can adjust the parameters to 
http://tile0.tianditu.com/DataServer?T=A0512_EMap&X=1&Y=1&L=3

so there is a bundle of files I need save,

now I need using programming to save its return png as a file(paste this url and you will see a png map file),.

So my aim is to get method to ther server, and get a lot of files and to save in my PC.

Former I do vc/c++ desktop dev and have no experience doing similar work, how should I do?
I want to use a programe to realize this task.

can somebody give some advice for me. should I use php, javascrip or c++ to do this?

Comment: yes. I want to know which method is fit my requirement and is easy to realize

Comment: If you are familiar with vb or c++, that seems a logical choice to write a small app. PHP seems like overkill, you'll need to run a web server to run your script, and javascript alone will make it difficult to save the files to your computer.

Comment: can be more details for c++, compare script I know more in c++

Comment: Perhaps another user can answer - I am not familiar with c++, but was just assisting with ruling out PHP / JS.